# Testing RxJS Timer With Http Call Inside

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a method `pollConnectivity` that uses the RxJS timer. Inside the `pollConnectivity` method I subecribe to my timer instance and it's first call is made after 0 seconds and then every 5 seconds thereafter. I am wondering how I would test this in Angular 6? This is what I currently have for my unit test but it doesn't seem to be working. I think I am close but also quite far off. An explanation of what I could be doing wrong would be super helpful. Thank you in advance for any help

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

import { ConnectivityService } from './connectivity.service';

let service: ConnectivityService;
let http: HttpClient;
let backend: HttpTestingController;

describe('ConnectivityService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [ConnectivityService],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule]
    });

    service = TestBed.get(ConnectivityService);
    http = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
    backend = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  describe('When the pollConnectivity method is called', () => {
    it('should hook into the timer observable and make a call to the correct endpoint', async () => {
      service.pollConnectivity();

      backend.expectOne({
        url: '',
        method: 'GET'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The implementation code:

```
import { Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ConnectivityService {
  private pollInstance: Observable<number>;

  public status: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.pollInstance = timer(0, 5000);
  }

  private getGpsStatus = () => {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/services/gps/status');
  }

  public pollConnectivity = () => {
    this.pollInstance.subscribe(() => {
      this.getGpsStatus().subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.status.next(response);
      });
    });
  }
}
```